# SwiftUI how to factor out animation from ButtonStyle so it can be reused

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

On my custom button style for macOS i use an animation which i want to factor out and use on other buttons / buttonStyles

i came up with this solution, which however for some reason doesn't animate

```
struct FButtonAnimation: ViewModifier {
    
    @State var configuration: ButtonStyleConfiguration
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.9 : 1)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.2), value: configuration.isPressed)
    }
    
}

struct FButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding([.top, .bottom], 6)
            .foregroundColor(configuration.role == .cancel ? Color.black : Color.white)
            .background((configuration.role == .cancel ? Color.white : Color.accentColor).opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.8 : 1) )
            .cornerRadius(6)
            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.25), radius: 2, x: 0, y: 0.5)
            .modifier(FButtonAnimation(configuration: configuration))
    }
}
```

So how to factor out the animation so it can be reused?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove state wrapper

```
struct FButtonAnimation: ViewModifier {
    
    var configuration: ButtonStyleConfiguration    // << here !!

    // ...
}
```

[image: demo]

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Comment: any idea why it didn't work with @State ?

Comment: State is initialized once and is expected to be changed from internal context, but it is not. Actually State is designed to be private always, so usage `private` is indicator if it is used correctly. In this case if we set private we would not be able to create, so State is wrong here and should not be used.